# Getting Mongoid to work with rails 3 along side active_record

Tags: mongodb, mongoid, mongoid3

in the installation guide to mongoid 3 it also explains how to disable active record,

the problem is I am trying to integrate Mongoid in an existing project that extensively uses active_record with mysql, and I have no intention to change that.

also I'm using squeel ontop of active_record.

anyway after I add the gem and try to do any action on active record I get the error below;

is Mongoid not meant to run WITH active_record anymore? I've used Mongoid 2 along size active_record with great success in the past. what's going on?

I'm using rails 3.2.9.

thx for any help,

this is the error I get:

NoMethodError: undefined method `to_sym' for #<Origin::Key:0x0000000851d788>
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:60:in`block in expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates'
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:59:in `each'
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/sanitization.rb:59:in`expand_hash_conditions_for_aggregates'
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/squeel-1.0.13/lib/squeel/adapters/active_record/relation_extensions.rb:248:in `block in build_where'
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/squeel-1.0.13/lib/squeel/adapters/active_record/relation_extensions.rb:243:in`map'
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/squeel-1.0.13/lib/squeel/adapters/active_record/relation_extensions.rb:243:in `build_where'
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:136:in`where'
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/squeel-1.0.13/lib/squeel/adapters/active_record/relation_extensions.rb:218:in `where'
    from /home/miki/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@simplee/gems/activerecord-3.2.9/lib/active_record/querying.rb:9:in`where'

Answer (score 0):

Here is some [code](http://blog.hashrocket.com/posts/bridging-activerecord-and-mongoid) that may help to bridge the gap between the two.